# Oracle - SQL query takes too much time

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have this tables:

- automa
- accoun
- client
- profil
- market

The biggest one is accoun, with almost 30 million rows. There are like 20 thousand rows in client, and 30 thousand rows in automa.

I need to get every row in automa, where:

- mktcode matches mktcode from market
- acccode matches acccode from accoun
- ccccode from accoun matches ccccode from client
- clicode from client matches clicode from profil
- procode from profil is 'ADMIN'

This is my query:

```
SELECT au.acccode, au.oprcode, au.ctrcode, au.ctrdesc, au.mkcode
FROM automa au
JOIN profil pr ON pr.procode = 'ADMIN'
JOIN client cl ON cl.clicode = pr.clicode
JOIN market mk ON mk.mktcode = au.mkcode
JOIN accoun ac ON ac.ccccode = cl.ccccode AND ac.acccode = au.acccode
GROUP BY au.acccode, au.oprcode, au.ctrcode, au.ctrdesc, au.mkcode
```

It takes like 60 seconds.

I have 2 extra problems:

- I cannot see the execution plan
- I cannot create indexes. If it's the only way, I could ask for them to be created, but that would take some time to be done.

Any ideas? I cannot figure out how to solve it without indexes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain why you cannot see the execution plan. Are you not allowed to run `EXPLAIN PLAN` ?

Comment: I'm not experienced in Oracle, but aren't 60 seconds for such a query in a table with 30 million rows joining other tables a normal amount?

Comment: Why do `GROUP BY` when no aggregate functions are involved? What's wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @jarlh when suitable indexes created( according to sql access advisor), to use `GROUP BY` will be faster than to use `DISTINCT`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, thank you for the information! (I'm not an Oracle guy, so I had no idea about that.)

Comment: @jarlh you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have no join condition between **automa** and **profil**. 
If you try

```
SELECT au.acccode, au.oprcode, au.ctrcode, au.ctrdesc, au.mkcode
  FROM automa au
  JOIN profil pr ON pr.procode = 'ADMIN'
```

this query returns ALL rows from automa, without any filtering.
Firstly, add join condition.

You can also try to rewrite this query. Because you need data only from **automa**, try to use EXISTS. May be after that you will not need in grouping/distinct. Something like that:

```
SELECT au.acccode, au.oprcode, au.ctrcode, au.ctrdesc, au.mkcode
  FROM automa au
 where exists (select null 
                from profil pr 
                JOIN client cl ON cl.clicode = pr.clicode and pr.procode = 'ADMIN'
                JOIN accoun ac ON ac.ccccode = cl.ccccode 
                              AND ac.acccode = au.acccode
                JOIN market mk ON mk.mktcode = au.mkcode
               )
```

Comment: There are no common fields between automa and pr.

Fields "clicode" from pr and cl, "ccccode" from cl and ac, and "acccode" from ac and automa have to be matched.